# Recursive algorithm to find all possible solutions in a nonogram row

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am trying to write a simple nonogram solver, in a kind of bruteforce way, but I am stuck on a relatively easy task. Let's say I have a row  with clues [2,3] that has a length of 10

so the solutions are:

```
$$-$$$----
$$--$$$---
$$---$$$--
$$----$$$-
$$-----$$$
-$$----$$$
--$$---$$$
---$$--$$$
----$$-$$$
-$$---$$$-
--$$-$$$--
```

I want to find all the possible solutions for a row
I know that I have to consider each block separately, and each block will have an availible space of n-(sum of remaining blocks length + number of remaining blocks) but I do not know how to progress from here

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @alseether, this is an algorithm question, so the language is not relevant. The OP is interested in the procedure.

Comment: @JonathanM Yeah, i know, but i will try to do it in c++ and just wanted to know if tht's ok for them.

Comment: BTW, i think you're missing some combinations, isn't `-$$-$$$---` a valid one too?

Comment: @alseether yes, I may have missed some combinations, indeed. And language is irrelevant to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<bool> tRow;

void printRow(tRow row){
    for (bool i : row){
        std::cout << ((i) ? '$' : '-');
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int requiredCells(const std::vector<int> nums){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : nums){
        sum += (i + 1); // The number + the at-least-one-cell gap at is right
    }
    return (sum == 0) ? 0 : sum - 1; // The right-most number don't need any gap
}

bool appendRow(tRow init, const std::vector<int> pendingNums, unsigned int rowSize, std::vector<tRow> &comb){
    if (pendingNums.size() <= 0){
        comb.push_back(init);
        return false;
    }
    int cellsRequired = requiredCells(pendingNums);
    if (cellsRequired > rowSize){
        return false;   // There are no combinations
    }
    tRow prefix;
    int gapSize = 0;
    std::vector<int> pNumsAux = pendingNums;
    pNumsAux.erase(pNumsAux.begin());
    unsigned int space = rowSize;
    while ((gapSize + cellsRequired) <= rowSize){
        space = rowSize;
        space -= gapSize;
        prefix.clear();
        prefix = init;
        for (int i = 0; i < gapSize; ++i){
            prefix.push_back(false);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pendingNums[0]; ++i){
            prefix.push_back(true);
            space--;
        }
        if (space > 0){
            prefix.push_back(false);
            space--;
        }
        appendRow(prefix, pNumsAux, space, comb);
        ++gapSize;
    }
    return true;
}

std::vector<tRow> getCombinations(const std::vector<int> row, unsigned int rowSize) {
    std::vector<tRow> comb;
    tRow init;
    appendRow(init, row, rowSize, comb);
    return comb;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> row = { 2, 3 };

    auto ret = getCombinations(row, 10);

    for (tRow r : ret){
        while (r.size() < 10)
            r.push_back(false);

        printRow(r);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

And my output is:

> $$-$$$----
>
> $$--$$$---
>
> $$---$$$--
>
> $$----$$$--
>
> $$-----$$$
>
> -$$-$$$----
>
> -$$--$$$--
>
> -$$---$$$-
>
> -$$----$$$-
>
> --$$-$$$--
>
> --$$--$$$-
>
> --$$---$$$
>
> ---$$-$$$-
>
> ---$$--$$$
>
> ----$$-$$$

For sure, this **must be** absolutely improvable.

Note: i did't test it more than already written case

Hope it works for you

Comment: If any case is forgotten, let me know and i will edit this answer

Comment: No, i was actually wrong, the "filling loop" must go up to 10, not 9 as i had

Answer (score 4):

Well, this question already have a good answer, so think of this one more as an advertisement of python's prowess.

```
def place(blocks,total):
    if not blocks: return ["-"*total]
    if blocks[0]>total: return []

    starts = total-blocks[0] #starts = 2 means possible starting indexes are [0,1,2]
    if len(blocks)==1: #this is special case
        return [("-"*i+"$"*blocks[0]+"-"*(starts-i)) for i in range(starts+1)]

    ans = []
    for i in range(total-blocks[0]): #append current solutions
        for sol in place(blocks[1:],starts-i-1): #with all possible other solutiona
            ans.append("-"*i+"$"*blocks[0]+"-"+sol)

    return ans
```

To test it:

```
for i in place([2,3,2],12):
    print(i)
```

Which produces output like:

```
$$-$$$-$$---
$$-$$$--$$--
$$-$$$---$$-
$$-$$$----$$
$$--$$$-$$--
$$--$$$--$$-
$$--$$$---$$
$$---$$$-$$-
$$---$$$--$$
$$----$$$-$$
-$$-$$$-$$--
-$$-$$$--$$-
-$$-$$$---$$
-$$--$$$-$$-
-$$--$$$--$$
-$$---$$$-$$
--$$-$$$-$$-
--$$-$$$--$$
--$$--$$$-$$
---$$-$$$-$$
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the python solution!

Comment: Really nice and compact solution